# Problem with PostgreSQL function parameters (Converting MySQL Stored Procedures)

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

I am converting a few simple MySQL stored procedures to PostgreSQL Functions and for some reason when I execute the following function it throws an error when executed.

I created the function with the following code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION cc.fs_ivr_updatecalltransfer(_ParentContactID
int[11], _CalledID varchar[32])
RETURNS int AS $$
DECLARE 
pcID int;   
BEGIN
if _ParentContactID<>0 then 
update cc.tblcontacts set cc.tblcontacts.transferdest =
_CalledID where cc.tblcontacts.contactid =
_ParentContactID;
end if;
RETURN _ParentContactID;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I Execute it manually like this:

```
SELECT cc.fs_ivr_updatecalltransfer(3,"test")
```

It throws this error:

```
SQL error:

ERROR:  column "test" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT cc.fs_ivr_updatecalltransfer(3,"test")
In statement: SELECT  cc.fs_ivr_updatecalltransfer(3,"test")
```

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use single quotes to quote strings, not double quotes. `'test'` means the string "test", whereas `"test"` means the identifier "test", which postgresql tries to resolve as a column, same as using backquotes in MySQL.